# Multi parameter response from Axis 2

Tags: web-services, apache-axis

I have a web service that returns multiple values. The current format of response looks like this

```
<ns:return>

  String....

</ns:return>
```

I have to have more meaningful responses that just 'return'. How can I do this with Axis 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer, You need to create an object and return the object as given below

```
return new workOrderResponse(workOrderId);
```

WorkOrderId object would need to have the required variables that needs to be returned along with the getters and setters